# Multicolored Polya Eggenberger Urn distributions

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

From an urn containing 1 ball each of $n$ different colours, a ball is drawn, its colour noted and then it is returned to the urn along with $k$ balls of the same colour.

what is the limit of the distribution of the number of balls of each colour?

what is the distribution of the first occurrence time of each colour?